# Access public control from different form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have been struggling with this for a while so I hope you can assist me.

I am attempting to get **Form 2** to set the text of my RichboxText (named "sourceCode") located in **Form 1** once a user clicks the button on **Form 2**.

I changed my RichboxText modifier to "public" and I am able to access the control by placing the following in my form 2 button:

```
private void buttoncreatetable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalVar.table = "<table" + " align=" + "\"" + alignment.Text + "\"" + " border=" + "\"" + bordersize.Value + "\"" + 
            " cellpadding=" + "\"" + padding.Value + "\"" + " cellspacing=" +
            "\"" + spacing.Value + "\"" + " style=" + "\"" + "width:" + width.Value + "px;"
            + " height:" + height.Value + "px;" + "\"" + ">" + Environment.NewLine + "<tbody>"; //end tbody, table, tr and td

        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
        form1.sourceCode.SelectedText = GlobalVar.table;
```

However the result of this code is that although it inserts the text into the Richbox, it creates an entirely *new *instance of Form 1 and does it, as opposed to inserting the text into the Richbox of the original instance of Form 1 without creating a new one.

I suspect the reason is because of this code: Form1 form1 = new Form1(); which instantiates a new copy of Form1. But without doing this there is no way of accessing Form 1 control properties easily.

Please assist me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is really bad design. One form should not be modifying properties on another form. The only case in which this makes sense is if you show a dialog box, in response to which you modify properties on the parent form. But then you have a reference to the dialog box form and can easily query its properties. You can hack it with `Application.OpenForms`, but I strongly recommend reconsidering your design.

Answer (score 1):

`Form firstForm = Application.OpenForms["FormName"];`

The `OpenForms` property is a very basic property that lists the forms that are currently open. Just use the form's name as ID.

[Click here for `OpenForms` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: What does it do that is undesirable to you?

Comment: Form form1 = Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
form1.sourceCode.SelectedText = GlobalVar.table;

This cannot access the control "sourceCode".

Comment: Maybe because `sourceCode` is private? Create a method in `Form1` with given string parameter that would update the text itself.

Comment: sourceCode is public. It still does not function.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `Form1` reference property in your `Form2` class.

```
public Form1 form1;
```

And assign it in your Main method (I assume you're initializing them there).

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form1.Show();
form2.Show();
form2.form1 = form1;
```

edit: Also, you should not change internal elements of one form from another. It breaks basic OO programming principles. Instead write yourself a method in `Form1`

```
void UpdateSelectedText(string updatedText)
{
    sourceCode.SelectedText = updatedText;
}
```

and then call it from `form2`

```
form1.UpdateSelectedText("Some new text");
```

Comment: I get the error: cannot assign "form 1" because it is a method group.

Comment: The code I provided cannot generate that kind of error - it says `form1` object in your `Form2` class is a method, which is not true. Revise your code again.

Comment: I think I am placing the second part of the code in the wrong area. Where is "main method" located?

Comment: In `Program.cs` file. I don't want to be rude, but it's basic knowledge. I assumed you did put your forms initialization there, because you didn't provide any details about that. However it's possible that you already included one form within another.

Comment: That's okay, I'm not very good at this stuff but I try and learn as I go along. I only know to initalise a form within a form. I added said code to main method but i recieve following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object for "form1.sourceCode.SelectedText = GlobalVar.table;" in button click